# Why can't I load images in phaser.io

Tags: javascript, loading, assets, phaser-framework

I keep getting the same errors

GET http://localhost:3000/star.png 404 (Not Found)

Phaser.Loader - image[star]: error loading asset from URL ./star.png

Phaser.Cache.getImage: Key "star" not found in Cache.

But I am not loading the asset incorrectly. Here is my code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html', "utf8");
  res.send(index);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Phaser</title>=

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
      preload: preload,
      create: create,
      update: update
    });

    function preload() {
      game.load.image('star', './star.png');
    };

    function create() {
      game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'star');
    };

    function update() {};
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my PATH for this game:
/home/me/dev/games/phaser

I have all my files (three files, app.js, index.html, and star.png) in the same directory (phaser). Why the heck does it not grab the .png file??? Am I not linking to it correctly? It's sitting right there, why does the GET request not grab it? Why does phaser.loader throw an error? I have tried a hundred different things but it just won't load. It's getting really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You are only hosting 1 route (`/`) - you need to serve the assets with a static server. See http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `game.load.image()` just adds to the loader queue.

You need to execute `game.load.start()` to actually kick the loading sequence off.

Comment: This doesn't fix it.